# What are the various methods to rightclick on a webelement in QTP?

Tags: qtp, right-click

I had to right click on a webelement. I tried the following methods:

*For code simplicity assume `webElem` refers to a valid `Browser().Page().WebElement()`.*

### 1)

```
Set obj=createobject("mercury.devicereplay")

getX = webElem.GetROProperty("abs_x")
getY = webElem.GetROProperty("abs_y")


'obj.MouseClick getX, getY,RIGHT_MOUSE_BUTTON
```

*THE ABOVE CODE DID NOT WORK*

### 2)

```
webElem.RightClick
```

*THIS CODE DID NOT WORK EITHER*

### 3) FOLLOWING CODE WORKED:

```
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2

webElem.RightClick

Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 1
```

## My questions are:

1. Why did I have to change the device replay type to make rightclick work? Where as, click method works fine.
2. Why, through `Mercury.DeviceReplay` object, the `MouseClick` method did not work?
3. How can I do this through `FireEvent` method? (please explain `FireEvent` method in detail, FYI: I am new to QTP)
4. What are the other methods to do this?

Could anyone please explain whay some methods work and some doesnt.

Thanks,
Srittam

Answer (score 3):

By default QTP runs most steps on web elements using *event replay* this means that it sends [DOM events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events) to the underlying DOM element. When a person interacts with the web page the browser generates many DOM events (e.g. `mousemove` `mousedown` `contextmenu`) and the web application may depend on any of these events in order to trigger the required behaviour. QTP does not know which events each web application will use and thus reproduces the subset that QTP's developers thought are interesting (for example for `Click` QTP replays `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `click`. For `RightClick` there is also a `contextmenu` event somewhere (I don't remember the order) and there is no `click`.

The probable reason that what you tried in **#2** failed is because there are additional events that the application expects which weren't created by QTP.

When you specify `ReplayType=2` (as in case **#3**) you tell QTP's web package to use *device replay* this means that it *physically* moves the mouse to the requested location and performs the operation. This means that the browser thinks a real person is moving the mouse and will reproduce exactly the same events as it would when a human being is performing the operation.

You should have gotton exactly the same results with case **#1** (explicitly using `DeviceReplay`). I can think of two reasons why it still failed.

1. In your code sample you have the line `'obj.MouseClick getX, getY,RIGHT_MOUSE_BUTTON` commented out, this is probably a copy/paste error but if this is also what you tried to run it would explain why nothing happened.
2. A more likely explanation is that you're using `abs_x` and `abs_y` to replay the click, this is the top left corner of the `WebElement` and perhaps this doesn't reach the correct DOM element. The way that `RightClick` in *device replay* mode differs from your implementation is that it clicks in the middle of the `WebElement` (by default) try getting the width and height of the element and doing: `obj.MouseClick getX+(width/2), getY+(height/2), RIGHT_MOUSE_BUTTON`

There is another way to perform a right click and that would be:

```
webElem.Click micNoCoordinates, micNoCoordinates, micRightBtn
```

But I would recomend against it since `webElem.RightClick` should work at least as well if not better.

Comment: Hi @Motti , I could understand clearly about how QTP works when it clicks/right cliks.

  I also want to know, if there is any way to know what are the DOM events generated by browser for a DOM element. Also, from where I can find out the complete set of DOM events followed by QTP in order for various actions? I want to find out which event did QTP miss or did not do in order, so the expected action did not happen.

Comment: @Srittam you can trace DOM events with several tools (e.g. DHTMLSpy) and you can use the same method while running a QTP test to see which events are generated. Note that it may be that the event that is missing is on a different DOM element than that you have in the script in which case QTP won't fire it in event mode.